# Django. How I can optimize db query?

Tags: django, database, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Status(models.Model): 

     CHOISES = ( 
         ('new', 'New'), 
         ('in_progress', 'InProgress'), 
         ('on_review', 'OnReview'), 
         ('tested', 'Tested'), 
         ('delivered', 'Delivered') 
     ) 

    status_type = models.CharField( 
    max_length=11, 
    choices=CHOISES, 
    primary_key=True) 

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey(status)
```

part of my view:

```
def task_list(request):

    all_tasks = Task.objects.all()
    tasks = {}

    tasks['new'] = all_tasks.filter(status_id='new')
    tasks['in_progress'] = all_tasks.filter(status_id='in_progress')
    tasks['on_review'] = all_tasks.filter(status_id='on_review')
    tasks['tested'] = all_tasks.filter(status_id='tested')
    tasks['delivered'] = all_tasks.filter(status_id='delivered')
....
```

part of my template:

```
{% for item in new %}
    <div id="{{ item.pk }}">
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% for item in in_progress %}
    <div id="{{ item.pk }}">
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}  
.....
```

The question is, is there any way to optimize all my querysets, or it is imposible to select five filters for one db call?
Like I understand, if I save in view only this call `all_tasks = Task.objects.all()` and then put logic in template, like this:

```
{% for item in all_task %}
{% if item.status_id == "new" %}
....
```

it will be exaclty five calls too
Hope my question is not too broad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just group your tasks by status in your view:

```
from itertools import groupby

def task_list(request):
    all_tasks = Task.objects.select_related('status').order_by('status')
    tasks = {status: list(tasks)
             for status, tasks
             in groupby(all_tasks, lambda x: x.status)}
```

And use them in your template like:

```
{% for task in tasks.new %}
  {{ task }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: great! thank you. Maybe it is stupid question, but how I can get task objects in template now? I dont need ordering list, with objects one by one. I need to put objects in five columns for each status, like in trello.com, so I need some condition.  If I use `{% if %}` tag for check status name, it will be db call anyway?

Comment: Queryset should be `Task.objects.select_related('status').order_by('status')`. In this case there will be no extra db queries.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to change your `CHOICES` (typo in there) to map to something that makes sense in ordering, eg integers.

Then perform a single query with orderby and in the template use the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag.

For whatever you may try, be careful not to fall in the trap of implementing SQL logic in Django just to avoid an extra query.

In any case, I would recommend you to use something like [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to have a grasp on times for any alternative.